# Assembly Language symbol table

Tags: assembly, x86

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVHBj.png

Above is assembly code, I need to make a symbol table out of it.
This is what I've got, I'm not sure if it is correct though?

```
Label    Section    Offset    Local?    Seq #
A        data       0x0       Global    0
fmt      rodata     0x0       local     1
main     text       0x0       local     2
loop     text       0x17      local     3
next1    text       0x30      local     4
next2    text       0x3d      local     5
done     text       0x5d      local     6
printf   ?           ?        global    7
```

Comment: @AndrewMedico What do you think they are, then? They are of course symbols. See also [section 5 in the GNU assembler's manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Symbols.html). *Of course not the blocks are the symbols, but the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` is wrong, it's just 3 bytes after `next2`. The rest looks okay, but you also missed `min` and `max` which were declared using the `.comm` directive on lines 4 and 5.

Comment: so does that mean that the sequence number would shift down? So the sequence number for A is 0, min is 1, max is 2, fmt is 3, etc...?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense.